# Whats different when you executable a scripts in OSX?

Tags: macos, shell, command-line-interface, zsh, finder

I have a question I have been trying to fix for a while. I want to understand what's the difference between starting a script from the command line and making it executable and then running it from the Finder.

Because this is what I am experiencing;

I have a simple script called *trash-files* which contains this command:

```
trash ~/Downloads/*
```

When I run from the terminal it works as expected; however if I doubleclick the shell script in the finder I see this:

```
/Users/xx/Desktop/trash-files: line 1: trash: command not found
```

I hope anyone can tell me why this doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 3):

`trash` is not a standard command in OS X. Is it something defined in your ~/.profile or a similar file? If so, these are not run for non-login shells, such as those created to run a script.

Comment: Yes, it is something defined in my profile, is there a way to load your profile when you double click it in the finder...

Comment: Non-login shells run ~/.bashrc instead of ~/.profile. You could add `if [ -f ~/.profile ]; then . ~/.profile; fi` to your ~/.bashrc (warning: this means it will sometimes be run repetitively, so if you do things like adding to PATH it can get quite long. Or, you could put that command at the beginning of the script... But what I'd really recommend is writing the script so it doesn't depend on your .profile setup at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using homebrew, you could run

```
brew install trash
```

which would install the necessary scripts to have the `trash` command work in the way you're expecting.

Comment: I just ran into the same issue and this did the trick. And if you're on OS X and developing you probably *should* be using Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

There is a folder in your home folder location called

```
.Trash
```

The "dot" in front of the folder name makes it hidden while searching for it in finder. You'll have to use Terminal to execute the following command:

```
cd ~/
ls -la
```

This will change the directory to the current logged in users home folder, then second command will list files and show hidden files. You can then run:

```
rm .Trash/*
```

This will remove everything inside the Trashcan on the dock. 
So open TextEdit from the /Applications folder, go to "Format" and make it "Plain Text". Paste in the two lines below.

```
#!/bin/sh
rm ~/.Trash/*
```

Save the file as "emptyTrash.sh" (uncheck use txt extension). Save it to your Desktop or wherever you'd like. Then open Terminal, cd (change directory) to where the files is and run this command to make the script executable:

```
chmod +x emptyTrash.sh
```

Then you can execute the script by cd (changing directory) to path where the script is, and run:

```
 ./emptyTrash.sh
```

That's it.